# MSAA - How to check if 2 automation elements refer to the same thing?

Tags: winapi, uiaccessibility, microsoft-accessibility

I am making an application which intends to behave like `inspect.exe`. I have a treeview of accessibility elements which are queried on demand as the user navigates through the elements. I want to implement the 'Watch Cursor' feature now.

I can obtain the currently hovered element using `AccessibleObjectFromPoint`. And I can call `IAccessible::get_accParent` until I reach the intersection point with my existing elements shown in the treeview. However, the object returned from this function is different to the object pointers returned from this property are different to the ones in my treeview representing the same UI element.

How do you go about comparing 2 elements and understanding whether they are equal?

Is there some UID that I can obtain from the IAccessible (or a similar interface) which can be used to uniquely identify elements?

Comment: That [msaa] tag is absolutely the wrong one to use in this case.

Comment: @Blindy Ohhh thanks, didn't realise it was an anti-aliasing tag, I'll change it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `IAccIdentity::GetIdentityString` is for.

1. Use `IUnknown::QueryInterface` for `IAccIdentity` (IID: `{7852B78D-1CFD-41C1-A615-9C0C85960B5F}`)
2. On the returned object call `IAccIdentity::GetIdentityString` with `dwIDChild` param set to `0`
3. Do a `memcmp` on the returned buffers.

additionally remember to call `CoTaskMemFree` after copying the identity string into memory.

Comment: Had a few issues because I used the wrong IID (should have looked at the IDL instead of using ChatGPT...). Added the IID to the answer. Also added that dwIDChild can be set to 0 to find the Identity of the current element.

Comment: what do you do when the `IAccIdentity` isn't implemented?