# IAccIdentity is not returning unique values?

Tags: winapi, uiaccessibility, microsoft-accessibility

As discussed in a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76789110/), I'm making an equivalent of `Inspect.exe`. To do this, I'm using `IAccIdentity` to obtain a "unique" ID of each control.

However, it turns out these IDs are **NOT** unique?

[image: Proof of non-uniqueness]

In this case, I could use `accName` to distinguish the elements, but I fear that this won't guarantee anything... Is there any method of obtaining a guaranteed unique reference to an element which is object instance independent?

Note: I concatenated the role in there too, to try to make it more unique, but failed.

Comment: `IAccIdentity` provides a unique identifier for `an accessible element`.

If you want to obtain a "unique" ID of each control. I suggest you could try to use [GetDlgCtrlID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgctrlid)

Comment: If you're writing an inspect equivalent, you should use UI Automation instead of MSAA, each element has a unique per desktop id IUIAutomationElement::GetRuntimeId: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationelement-getruntimeid

Comment: @SimonMourier From the docs: "`AutomationIdProperty` does not guarantee a unique identity throughout the tree" - so from what I gather this won't be helpful either?

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT These 2 controls have the same `hwnd`... So i'd imagine they'd have the same `CtrlID` too?

Comment: I talked about RuntimeId, not AutomationId, they are different things.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, it is impossible to have the same HWND in the same desktop. In my opinion, If the hwnd is the same, the CtrlID is the same.